# How to restore WordPress database from 000webhost free plan as i have deleted my database by mistake?

Tags: database, wordpress, phpmyadmin, recovery

I have a free hosting plan of 000webhost. I have installed WordPress on it. And by mistake, I deleted my database. So, there is any way to recover the database in the free plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a question you should ask 000webhost support rather than a general forum like Stack Overflow.

Since you've tagged phpMyAdmin, I can tell you that phpMyAdmin (and MySQL itself) does not have a way to recover the database and trusts that you meant to delete it. If you don't have an SQL file backup then your best hope is to see if your hosting provider automatically backs up your databases on your behalf. Good luck.